# BQ: How to UNNEST into new table

Tags: google-maps, google-bigquery

I'm exporting billing data from Google Cloud Platform to BigQuery (BQ).
The task at hand is to build a query that UNNEST relevant data to a new 'flat' table
The structure of the data in BQ is this:

```
[{
"billing_account_id": "01234-1778EC-123456",
"service": {
  "id": "2062-016F-44A2",
  "description": "Maps" 
},
"sku": {
  "id": "5D8F-0D17-AAA2",
  "description": "Google Maps"
},
"usage_start_time": "2018-11-05 14:45:00 UTC",
"usage_end_time": "2018-11-05 15:00:00 UTC",
"project": {
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "labels": []
},
"labels": [],
"system_labels": [],
"location": null,
"export_time": "2018-11-05 21:54:09.779 UTC",
"cost": "5.0",
"currency": "EUR",
"currency_conversion_rate": "0.87860000000017424",
"usage": {
  "amount": "900.0",
  "unit": "seconds",
  "amount_in_pricing_units": "0.00034674063800277393",
  "pricing_unit": "month"
},
"credits": "-1.25",
"invoice": {
  "month": "201811"
}
```

},

I wish to schedule a job that builds a new table every day with just this schema

```
billing_account_id, usage_start_time, usage_end_time, cost, credit_amount
```

So far I'm at this:

```
select billing_account_id, usage_start_time, usage_end_time, cost, credits AS CREDITS from clientBilling.gcp_billing_export_v1_XXXX , UNNEST(credits);
```

But in the results **credits are still nested** and not 'flat' as I need. Any input is welcome, thanks! :)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zgu5.jpg)

Comment: Hi there - you have actually unnested credits with your use of `UNNEST(credits)` - could you give some more detail on how you'd like the results to look?

Comment: Hi @Ben P, please see the image attached ("result") in the post above. I get a structure with credits - and inside I have .name and .amount. The goal is to have rows with just five columns; billing_account_id, usage_start_time, usage_end_time, cost, credits_amount

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`credits` is an array of structs (each struct being "name, amount") - a "repeated" record in BigQuery - so you have to first unnest the array and then reference the struct member you want.

Thus:

1. `UNNEST` the credits record
2. Alias the credits.amount struct member as credit_amount

`` SELECT
  billing_account_id,
  usage_start_time,
  usage_end_time,
  cost,
  credit.amount as credit_amount
FROM
  `optimum-rock-145719.billing_export.gcp_billing_export_v1*`,
  UNNEST(credits) as credit ``

This will return a result table with just the credits.amount column as credits_amount. You were doing step 1, but not step 2, and ignoring the unnested fields in your `SELECT` clause.